# Cannot determine raw type of Enumeration in Slick GetResult extractor

Tags: scala, slick

I've a lot of `GetResult` extractors which do convert string values to `Enumeration` types. This leads to a lot of boilerplate code and so I thought I can write a generic extractor for all `Enumeration` types.

```
implicit def stringToEnum[T <: Enumeration : ClassTag] = new GetResult[T#Value] {
  def apply(rs: PositionedResult) = {
    val c = implicitly[ClassTag[T]].runtimeClass
    val enum = c.getField("MODULE$").get(null).asInstanceOf[T]
    val value = rs.nextString()
    enum.toOpt(value).getOrElse(throw new Exception(
      "Unexpected value: " + value + " for enum: " + enum.getClass.getName)
    )
  }
}
```

The `toOpt` method converts a string value to an `Enumeration` value if possible.

```
implicit class StringToEnum[T <: Enumeration](enum: T) {
  def toOpt(action: String): Option[T#Value] = {
    enum.values.find(_.toString == action)
  }
}
```

The code compiles fine. But on runtime the `Enumeration` type is determined as `scala.runtime.Nothing` and therefore I cannot get a reference to the `Enumeration` type.

Can someone explain me why the type is `scala.runtime.Nothing` and not the type of the `Enumeration`. And is there an other solution to solve this problem.